# Testing Image onload using jsdom, sinon, mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jsdom, sinon-chai

Can anyone help me with testing of following function

```
function onload(cb){
  const image = 'http://placehold.it/350x150'
  const img = new Image()
  img.src = image
  img.onload = () => {
    cb()
  }
}
```

In my test file `Image` is available via jsdom. I want that I can test that `cb` is calledOnce

Answer (score 6):

### Option 1: active external resource loading in JSDOM

Initializing JSDOM with `resources: 'usable'` should normally be enough with the latest API (`v10+`):

```
const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>',{
    resources: 'usable'
});
const { window } = jsdom;
```

It requires the `canvas` ([canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) or [canvas-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-prebuilt)) module as stated in [JSDOM doc](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#loading-subresources).

---

### Option 2: mock window.Image to gain control over it

Using the latest `canvas` module, you can mock the `window.Image` to trigger `load` events.

So first create a mock for the `window.Image` class:

```
import CanvasImage from 'canvas/lib/image';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import { URL } from 'url';
import request from 'request';
// Where to fetch assets on the file system when path are provided.
const ASSETS_DIRECTORY = path.join(__dirname,'.');

const WindowImage = function() {    
    // Reimplemented the following class:
    // https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLImageElement-impl.js
    // https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#imagesrcbuffer
    let source;
    let image;
    let onload;
    let onerror;
    return {
        set src (value) {
            // TODO Throw errors to the Image.onerror handler.
            const onDataLoaded = function (data) {
                image = new CanvasImage();
                image.onload = () => {
                    if (onload) {
                        onload(image);
                    }
                };
                image.onerror = err => {
                    if (onerror) {
                        onerror(err);
                    }
                };
                image.src = data;
                source = value;
            };
            // URL or path?
            let url;
            try {
                url = new URL(value);
            } catch (e) {}
            // Fetch the data.
            if (url) {
                request(url.href, (error, response, body) => {
                    if (response && response.statusCode !== undefined && response.statusCode !== 200) {
                        throw new Error("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
                    }
                    onDataLoaded(body);
                });
            } else {
                // Assume it is a file path: try a local file read.
                fs.readFile(path.join(ASSETS_DIRECTORY,value),function (err,data) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    onDataLoaded(data);
                });
            }
        },
        set onload (handler) {
            onload = handler;
        },
        set onerror (handler) {
            onerror = handler;
        },
        get src () {
            return source;
        },
        // TODO Should allows to modify height and width
        // + add natural height and width
        // Cf. https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLImageElement-impl.js#L51
        get width () {
            return image && image.width;
        },
        get height () {
            return image && image.height;
        }
    };
};
```

Then you can mock `window.Image` in your tests, by redefining the one used by JSDOM:

```
window.Image = WindowImage;
```

This is not really elegant, but it gives you control over how image data is loaded, as [`canvas.Image.src`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#imagesrcbuffer) can normally take any Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Vitest:

onload.ts:

```
export function onload(cb: CallableFunction) {
  const image = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = image;
  img.onload = () => {
    cb();
  };
}
```

onload.test.ts:

```
// @vitest-environment jsdom

import { describe, expect, it, vi, afterEach, beforeEach } from 'vitest';
import { onload } from './onload.ts';

describe(`fn onload`, () => {
  const event = {} as Event;
  let img: HTMLImageElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    vi.spyOn(window, 'Image').mockImplementation(() => {
      img = {} as HTMLImageElement;
      return img;
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    vi.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  it('should call the callback function once on image load', () => {
    const cb = vi.fn();

    onload(cb);
    img.onload?.(event);

    expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();
  });
});
```